# Environment conflicts with WickedPDF and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, wicked-pdf

I am using WickedPDF, and I have basically two gems that include the binaries:

```
gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", "1.0.0"
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary", "0.9.5.3"
```

The first one is supposed to be just for production, and the second one for development.  The deployment to Heroku doesn't work if I have my Gemfile like:

```
group :development do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary", "0.9.5.3"
end

group :production do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", "1.0.0"
end
```

And it doesn't work either if I have it like:

```
group :production do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", "1.0.0"
end
```

It just works if I have it without groups. Just like:

```
gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", "1.0.0"
```

The error that I get is:

**RuntimeError: Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown**

Why would this happen? Why Heroku is not using the production group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WickedPdf tries to figure out where the wkhtmltopdf binary lives, but can have a hard time on some systems (particularly shared servers).

You probably have to set it manually in an initializer something like this:

```
bin_location = case Rails.env
  when 'production' then "/wherever/your/binary/is/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
  when 'development' then "/local/path/to/wkthmltopdf"
  else `which wkhtmltopdf`
end
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => bin_location }
```

Comment: I am using two gems though...One in the production group and another in the development group... That shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: @HommerSmith Just have them both without groups, the config will sort out which one wicked_pdf will run (if you have the paths setup right).

Comment: that doesn't happen as I explained in my question.